# Are questions about specific open source projects on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about specific open source projects on-topic? I mean questions like:

- Why is project X the way it is and not other?
- Where can I get support for project Y?
- Why did project A split into B and C?

I know these would be better answered by particular projects but (1) there may be users/developers of those projects here too and (2) sometimes a view/opinion from "outsider" is valuable too.

Comment: Please guys, the wording is similar but the questions are not dupes.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I'd say it's a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/q/176/168)

Comment: @overactor I agree with that

Comment: For the sake of giving my thoughts, here's my nickels (I know, in the comments)... The site is not customer support, therefore, if I'm asking *Why does this do that*, it would be horrible. Half of us don't know, and more than half probably don't care. Go ask the maintainers and contributors themselves. I don't mind having questions that ask for rationale, because they concern the organization and development of open projects, which is in our scope.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents about this: I think questions about specific projects can be on-topic, if they are related to the openness of the project or the open development model.

To your questions in particular. #1 and #3 seem opinion-based to me. #2 seems to have no connection to the openness of the project.